# How to set the color for a scatter plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I used this code to create a scatter plot for palmer penguins dataset

1. when I try to put any specific color it gives me an error I don't know why :

```
ggplot(data = penguins) + 
    geom_point(mapping = aes(x = flipper_length_mm, y = body_mass_g)color = "purple")
```

2. I tried another code but it give me instead light red :

```
ggplot(data = penguins) + 
    geom_point(mapping = aes(x = flipper_length_mm, y = body_mass_g, color = "purple"))
```

I was expecting to change the whole color for the one I wanted

Comment: The issue with your first code is a missing `,` before`color = "purple"`, i.e. do `geom_point(mapping = aes(x = flipper_length_mm, y = body_mass_g), color = "purple")`. The issue with your second code is that you mapped on the `color` aesthetic. If you want to set the color for all points then do that outside of `aes()` as in your first code.